# On click of shared video how to navigate to facebook app

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

After sharing a video from my application if I will open the facebook in mobile browser and on click of video I want to redirect to native facebook app. How it can be possible using facebook open graph tags in PHP.

Comment: The *application* you mention, is that a web based app or mobile app?  It's not very clear what you're asking, could you please spend a bit more time and give us more background and structure your question out more please.

Comment: The application is web based application from where you can share the video. After sharing the video if some one will open it in facebbok in mobile browser and click on shared video it should open in native facebook app. Thanks @JujharSingh